# formatCurrency not working after AJAX call

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am using format currency jQuery plugin to add a `$` in front of some numbers. I also have a table that uses an AJAX call to sort the table. When the page loads initially, the `$` is added correctly. But, when I sort the table, the function is not called and my numbers lose the `$`. Is there something like `$(window).load` for an AJAX call?

I should mention that the table sorting is also done through a plugin, so I do not want to edit the plugin's files. I would like to add this to my `main.js` file just in case the plugin gets an update.

Here is what I have so far that is not working with the AJAX call:

```
(function($){
    $(window).load(function(){
        $('.currency, .amount-applied').formatCurrency({
            roundToDecimalPlace: 0
        });
    });
})(jQuery);
```

Answer (score 1):

The AJAX call that sorts the table should have a callback function defined.  If so, that's where you want to put your formatCurrency() call.  $(window).load() doesn't fire after an AJAX call.

What plugin are you using to sort the table?  If you point us in the right direction we can get you sorted (haha, see what I did there?)

Comment: LOL!!! That was a good one! The plugin I am using is WP-Types Views plugin. The sort functionality is built in. Since I am sorting the columns and also using filters, I would probably need to add the function to more than one callback. I am looking to try and find where I need to put it.